# Deploying release jar error -Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request

Tags: java, linux, maven, unix

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:
deploy-file (default-cli) on project datatest: 
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.sabre:datatest:jar:sources:1.3.2-release from/toupload-releases (http://maven.sabre.com/content/repositories/releases): 
Failed to transfer file: http://maven.sabre.com/content/repositories/releases/com/sabre/
datatest/1.3.2-release/datatest-1.3.2-release-sources.jar.
Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request. -> [Help 1]

Not sure why am I getting this error ?

Comment: 400 means you have already an artifact with this version. So you need to create a different version 1.3.3 for example....